# then() is not being triggered on a promise function

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using promise function in my application. Attached below is my code:

```
module.exports = function (path)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        fs.readFileAsync(path, encoding='UTF-8')
        .then(function(data) {
            return wmReuters.parseXMLtoJSON(data);
            }).then(function(jsonedData) {

            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                resolve({
                    'name': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].contentMeta[0].slugline[0]['_'],
                    'description': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].contentMeta[0].headline[0]['_'],
                    'date': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].itemMeta[0].firstCreated[0],
                    'ingestDate': new Date(),
                    'lastModified': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].itemMeta[0].versionCreated[0],
                    'sourceId': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].contentMeta[0].altId[0]['_'],
                    'sourceNmae': 'Reuters',
                });

            });

        }).catch(function(err) {
            reject(new Error('Parsing Error: ' + err));
    });
});

}
```

and I called this function in another file (this function is imported as parser)

```
parser('./Ingestor/XMLs/2014script/2014-01-01T000815Z_3_WNE9CUATJ_RTRWNEC_0_2210-UAE-DUBAI-NEW-YEAR-FIREWORKS.XML').then(function(obj) {
console.log(obj);
}).then(function(clip) {
console.log(clip);
}).catch(function(err) {console.log(err);})
```

The first then() attached after parser is never triggered. I wonder what is wrong with my code( There is probably something wrong with resolve I guess but I am not sure where)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never resolving the top most promise that is returned so the caller's `.then()` handler never gets called.  Instead of creating new promises, you can just use the ones you already have by returning the `fs.readFileAsync()` promise have like this:

```
module.exports = function (path) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(path, encoding='UTF-8')
    .then(function(data) {
        return wmReuters.parseXMLtoJSON(data);
        }).then(function(jsonedData) {
            return {
                'name': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].contentMeta[0].slugline[0]['_'],
                'description': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].contentMeta[0].headline[0]['_'],
                'date': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].itemMeta[0].firstCreated[0],
                'ingestDate': new Date(),
                'lastModified': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].itemMeta[0].versionCreated[0],
                'sourceId': jsonedData.newsMessage.itemSet[0].packageItem[0].contentMeta[0].altId[0]['_'],
                'sourceNmae': 'Reuters',
            };
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        throw (new Error('Parsing Error: ' + err));
    });
}
```

FYI, you may have a misspelling  in `sourceNmae: 'Reuters'`.

Comment: I solved it by adding .then(resolve, reject) after catch(function(err)). Still, nice catch!

Comment: @TheCoolestPenguin - `.then(resolve, reject)` is an anti-pattern (waste of code and not needed).  It should never be needed.  If you study and copy my answer, you will see that you don't need to create your own promise at all.  You can just return the one that `fs.readFileAsync()` already created and just chain your other operations onto that one promise.

Comment: Thanks! Was not that much into promise. I understand it much better now.